# JSON, Object & Class confusion

Tags: javascript, json, object

I've lately read a lot about JSON and JavaScript object. But I become more and more confused, couse to me, they quite often look the same.

I have created an JavaScript class which I instantiate to an object like this:

```
function Person(Name, Lastname, Age, sGender)
{
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Lastname = Lastname;
    this.Age = Age;
    this.sGender = sGender;
}


var person = new Person(
    $('#PersonName').val(),
    $('#PersonLastName').val(),
    $('#PersonLastName').val(),
    $('#PersonAge').val(),
    $("#gender input[type='radio']:checked").val()
);
```

The #PersonName etc. are from my HTML input boxes. And at this part I know what it is that I'm doing.

But then I read about a simpler way of creating an object, so I gave it a go:

```
var oPerson = 
{
    "Name": $('#PersonName').val(),
    "Lastname": $('#PersonLastName').val(),
    "Age": $('#PersonAge').val(),
    "sGender": $("#gender input[type='radio']:checked").val()
}
aPeople.push(oPerson);
return oPerson;
```

But now I'm just really confused about what the code above is. Is this JSON or just a JavaScript object?

I hope that some of you bright minds can shed some light on this for me. :)

Comment: The top code is a Class, Bottom code is a standard JS object.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2904131/497356

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON = JavaScript Object Notation. That is, JSON is the text representation of a JavaScript object. The JSON notation happens to have the same syntax as JavaScript objects (or at least, a style of JavaScript objects).

Anytime you're creating an object in JavaScript (as in the code above), it's a JavaScript object. When you're transferring a JavaScript object as text, then you can use the JSON notation which is very natural in JavaScript. But you could also use an alternative format, such as XML or even a proprietary format.

But JSON is merely a representation of an object. When it's in code, it's an actual object.

Answer (score 0):

The first example creates a class `Person` and instantiates it into a `Person` object.
The second example just creates an object literal, which is just a plain Javascript object.

None of the above is JSON, which is a string representation of an array or object. For example, this is JSON:

```
var json = '{ "Name": "John", "LastName" : "Adnaves" }';
```

As you can see it very closely resembles a Javascript object but the key point is it's a string.

Answer (score 0):

The second case is called Object Literal Notation, the syntax for it looks like this:

```
{
    propertyName: value;
    propertyName2: value,
    .
    .
    propertyNameN: value
}
```

The first case you mentioned creates a class for `Person`, or to be more exact: it is a constructor function used to create instances of `Person`.

It is useful when you want to create objects that inherit functionality and share common attributes with each other.

JSON *(as have @Pete said too) is Javascript Object Notation.

It's syntax is very similar to Object literals, but there are certain things which JSON can't represent *(Object Literal Notation can do that)* like functions, RegExps objects, infinity, NaN, undefined, etc ..

In other words, JSON is the string representation of an Object and it is used to transfer that object *(mostly its properties, state if you will)* across different computers.